# How to fix "Cannot resolve {thymeleaf placeholder}" in Spring/Intellij?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

In the process of trying to resolve a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685234/how-to-make-el-work-with-intellij-tomcat-8-spring-mvc) I've been looking at switching to thymeleaf due to the supposed benefits and tried a simple starter app using Spring Boot.

However, when I use `th` in my html page it gives me a **"Cannot resolve 'var'"** error. I was able to resolve this error with this ugly hack found on IntelliJ's tracker:

```
// hack for Thymeleaf plugin - duplicate model properties
if (false) {
    WebContext context = new org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext(null, null, null);
    // Here we must dup all model attributes
    context.setVariable("name", name);
}
```

Which makes the controller look like, for example:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
                       Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);

    // This code is repetitive and bloating
    // Every model attribute must be added here!
    if (false) {
        WebContext context = new org.thymeleaf.context.WebContext(null, null, null);
        context.setVariable("name", name);
    }
    return "greeting";
}
```

Ugly, for one, because this code generates an obvious warning about the pointless `if (false)` but also because I'm going to have a number of views and controllers and it's frankly embarrassing. If it was a one-time-one-place thing I'd overlook it; not the case.

While learning about Spring and Boot and all the config possibilities, I've noticed that there are ways to inform Spring of various conditions which will allow it to better help you. For example, supplying metadata to aid in content assist in a properties file (sorry, I'm new so this may not be a relevant example).

Is there any cleaner way to fix the "Cannot resolve 'var'" error?

I've tried to make adjustments to the thymeleaf properties in my application properties file but all the default values seem to be correct.

Using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 14.1.3 and 4.

Comment: AN error in Intellij when editing or runtime? If it is the first, ignore it I would say or add an issue with Jetbrains to have this fixed.

Comment: @M.Deinum, it's during editing and it does work at runtime. The problem with ignoring it though is I lose content assist and auto complete which isn't life ending but definitely inconvenient and less productive. In my actual code those errors will be abundant. I think it's already an issue but I'll have to re-track it down to verify. If I remember it is currently low priority and unverified. Thanks!

Comment: Add your Thymeleaf template to the question and the EXACT error and top part of stackframe in exception.  Somewhere there is a variable name of `'var'` this is what can not be resolved.  It seems to have nothing to do with a variable name of `'name'`

Comment: @Darryl, that's not the case. It's not an exception so there's no way to give a more exact error description. It's an error in IDEA but works fine when running. It is `name` as can be seen in the hack that fixes the error as well. `var` is just the generic name given in the error. I have opened an issue with Jet and it's actually a known issue that is planned to be fixed in an upcoming release.  I can link you to the issue when I'm back on a real machine. Thanks.

Comment: @DarrylMiles, [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738#comment=27-1210036) is the issue they rolled mine into. Looks like 3.1.2016 is the proposed fix date.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Since the introduction of `var` to the Java language, this question is now very misleadingly titled. I'd say the view count is disproportionately high for this kind of question, so I expect it hasn't helped a lot of the viewers it's received. It seems like the best thing to do is either to heavily edit it, or, given that it's a fixed bug, maybe just deleting it altogether. Would you be open to the latter? If not, I'm happy to edit it.

Comment: @Michael, I missed your comment from long ago. You're probably right about its usefulness so I'm happy to delete it.